# Generating all possible combinations between multiple members in multiple teams

Tags: r

I would like to transform the following dataframe in R:

```
df <- data.frame (project  = c("P1", "P1", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P3", "P3"),
members = c("a", "b", "a", "c", "d", "e", "f")
)
```

into:

```
df2 <- data.frame (project1 = c("P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1"),
                   project2 = c("P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P3", "P3", "P3", "P3"),
                   members1 = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "b", "b"),
                   members2 = c("a", "c", "d", "a", "c", "d", "e", "f", "e", "f")
)
```

In other words, I would like to compare each member of one project to all members of another project, and do this for all possible combinations of projects.

My first take was to transform df into a matrix of matrices, where the rows and cols are P1 to P3, and inside each cell is a second matrix of the corresponding members, hoping I could then use the melt() function to turn it into df2, but I am really stuck, because I'm not even sure this is the right approach and I can't create the matrix anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Base R:

```
my_fun <- function(x){
  a <- setNames(as.list(names(x)), paste0('project', 1:2))
  b <- setNames(expand.grid(x), paste0("member", 1:2))
  cbind(a, b)
}


do.call(rbind, combn(split(df$members, df$project), 2,my_fun, simplify = FALSE))

   project1 project2 member1 member2
1        P1       P2       a       a
2        P1       P2       b       a
3        P1       P2       a       c
4        P1       P2       b       c
5        P1       P2       a       d
6        P1       P2       b       d
7        P1       P3       a       e
8        P1       P3       b       e
9        P1       P3       a       f
10       P1       P3       b       f
11       P2       P3       a       e
12       P2       P3       c       e
13       P2       P3       d       e
14       P2       P3       a       f
15       P2       P3       c       f
16       P2       P3       d       f
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `tidyr`'s `crossing` with some left joins (here `dplyr`). I've added a `filter` to get your desired output, but you can omit this to get all possible combinations.

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

crossing(project_1 = df$project,  project_2 = df$project) |>
  left_join(df |> rename(project_1 = project, members_1 = members), multiple = "all") |>
  left_join(df |> rename(project_2 = project, members_2 = members), multiple = "all") |>
  filter(project_1 != project_2,
         project_1 == "P1")
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 10 × 4
   project_1 project_2 members_1 members_2
   <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>    
 1 P1        P2        a         a        
 2 P1        P2        a         c        
 3 P1        P2        a         d        
 4 P1        P2        b         a        
 5 P1        P2        b         c        
 6 P1        P2        b         d        
 7 P1        P3        a         e        
 8 P1        P3        a         f        
 9 P1        P3        b         e        
10 P1        P3        b         f
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `combn` + `split`

```
do.call(
  rbind,
  combn(
    split(df, ~project), 2,
    FUN = function(v) {
      setNames(
        merge(v[1], v[2], all = TRUE),
        outer(names(df), 1:2, paste0)
      )
    },
    simplify = FALSE
  )
)
```

which gives

```
   project1 members1 project2 members2
1        P1        a       P2        a
2        P1        b       P2        a
3        P1        a       P2        c
4        P1        b       P2        c
5        P1        a       P2        d
6        P1        b       P2        d
7        P1        a       P3        e
8        P1        b       P3        e
9        P1        a       P3        f
10       P1        b       P3        f
11       P2        a       P3        e
12       P2        c       P3        e
13       P2        d       P3        e
14       P2        a       P3        f
15       P2        c       P3        f
16       P2        d       P3        f
```